# Help me understand transformers

Tags: transformer

I don't know why, but I can't understand how a transformer is not providing more power to a load.

If I connect a 1 Ω load to a 120 V source I would get 14.4 kW, but if I connected the load to the source through a step-up transformer I get 1.44 MW.

[image]

Comment: assuming all components are ideal, what's the problem?

Comment: A higher voltage through a 1 ohm resistor will result in more current through the resistor and hence more power.

Comment: To put 1.44 MW into your load the ideal transformer must be taking 1.44 MW from your supply. There's no magic here.

Comment: @Claaay I think you are confusing MW (megawatts) with mW (milliwatts).

Comment: @PStechPaul 1.44 MW is correct here.

Answer (score 6):

A transformer transforms the resistance the power supply sees. It does this by stepping up/down the voltage.

In your example, without the transformer, V1 is connected to a 1 ohm resistor,  so: 
 power = (120 V)<sup>2</sup>/1 ohm = 14.4 kW.
After the transformer is connected, the effective resistance is now 0.01 ohm, changing the equation to: 
power = (120 V)<sup>2</sup>/0.01 ohm = 1.44 MW
Of course, the resistance doesn't actually change, but the resistor now sees 1200 V, which gives the same value  if you calculate from the resistor's side:
power = (1200 V)<sup>2</sup>/1 ohm = 1.44 MW

Assuming your power supply V1 can handle the increased power, using the transformer allows you to deliver much more power to the load. You can't change the voltage of the power supply, or the load resistance, but the transformer allows you to balance the two by increasing the voltage to the resistor and decreasing the resistance presented to the supply.

Answer (score 1):

With a 1 ohm resistor, **current** is proportional to **voltage** per Ohm's Law.

```
  V (volts) = I (amps) x R (ohms).
```

At 120V, a 1 ohm resistor is 120 amps.
At 1200V, a 1 ohm resistor is 1200 amps.
*Not rocket science so far*.

But you were asking about *power*.   Power follows a different formula

```
  P (watts or VA) =  V (volts) x I (amps).
```

So remember those figures just above? At 120V and 120A, what is P?
OK, let's do it again.  At 1200V and 1200A, what is P?
By golly I think you got it.

Story problem.  Your buddy has a 120V circuit out to a chicken shed. The chickens need warmth and your buddy uses a 100 watt incandescent light.  But that has to be checked 6 times a day to make sure it hasn't burned out.  Your buddy wants a quality, permanent hardwired heater that will produce *in the neighborhood of* 100 watts.  Home Depot must stock it, but all their quality heaters *that are simple resistors, with no fan or electronics*, are 240V and start at [350W](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cadet-24-in-240-208-volt-350-262-watt-Electric-Baseboard-Heater-in-White-2F350W/202832888) to [500W](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cadet-35-in-240-208-volt-500-375-watt-SoftHeat-Hydronic-Electric-Baseboard-Heater-in-White-EBHN500W/305714133). What will you do?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you suddenly converted 14.4 kW into 1.44 MW (and solved the humanity's energy needs), then no, that's not quite what happens.

With your transformer, this is what happens:

- You have an input voltage of 120 V.
- The transformer takes 120 V in, and gives 1200 V out.
- The voltage across the resistor is 1200 V, which at \$1\space\Omega\$, means the current across the resistor is 1200 A, and you do indeed draw 1.44 MW (it's going to be balmy in that room!).
- But the transformer must provide that power, which means the power into the transformer must also be 1.44 MW.
- That means the current in the circuit involving the source and the primary winding is now **12 kA**
- That also means the source must be able to provide that amount of power.

Your (ideal) source may be defined by its voltage, but the load you connect to it then defines the current and power it must be able to generate. You did not "transform" 14.4 kW into 1.44 MW, you built a circuit where the source must now provide 1.44 MW. Exactly as if you had a \$0.01\space\Omega\$ resistor where you had your original \$1\space\Omega\$ resistor.

In reality, with most sources, if you try to draw 100 times more current and power than initially designed for, at least one of these things will happen:

- Something will just break (probably melt down).
- A circuit breaker will prevent the above from happening.
- The source which is not really an *ideal* source has an internal resistance. That resistance means that as current goes up, voltage goes down. Most likely in this case voltage will end up being 0 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer turns ratio 1:10 is directly correlated to the voltage ratio:

\$ 10*V_{1} = 1*V_{2} \$

And with this information, you can proceed to calculate the power using [Joule's Law](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/electronics/general-electronics/the-power-of-joules-law-in-electronics-141437/):

\$ P_1 = \frac{(V_1)^2}{R_1} = \frac{(120)^2}{1} = 14.400 \space kW \$

\$ P_2 = \frac{(10*V_1)^2}{R_2} = \frac{100(120)^2}{1} = 1440.0 \space kW \$

As you can see in these calculations, it confirms that the transformer circuit is *in fact* delivering more power to the 1 Ohm load compared to the simple circuit.

And this is the expected behavior since you are driving x10 more voltage into the same resistive load and thus it should draw x100 more power due to the exponential (square) relationship of Power and Voltage \$ (P = V^2/R) \$.